# How to update ViewModel from View in mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to update ViewModel from view in mvvmcross, Can i update it ? I have tried messenger pluging but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: The messenger plugin is typically used for this.  If you can explain what didn't work, or show some code, perhaps we can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is you can use the View's `ViewModel` property and cast it to your type of ViewModel. After that you can access everything that you want to execute or change.

A very simple example using Droid and Core projects would be:

**MainView**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using Core.ViewModels;

namespace Droid.Views
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected MainViewModel MainViewModel 
        {
            get { return ViewModel as MainViewModel; } 
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_view);

            MainViewModel.ChangePropertyToEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

And then our ViewModel:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        #region TestProperty

        private string _testProperty;

        public string TestProperty
        { 
            get { return _testProperty; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _testProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        public void ChangePropertyToEmpty()
        {
            TestProperty = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do is just typecast it in the view class.

```
MainViewModel model= (MainViewModel)this.ViewModel;
model.ChangePropertyEmpty()
```

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that. It is just my experience that usually if I would need to call the `ViewModel`, I need to do it multiple times, thus I just write it down as a property directly :) Glad it helped